# Which one is more efficient in performance, "x>=a" or "x>a || x==a"?

Tags: c#

I don't know the internal implementation of the following. Shortly speaking, which one is more efficient in performance, `x>=a` or `x>a || x==a`?

### Edit 1:

Let's divide it into 2 cases:

- when both `a` and `x` are in the same type.
- when `a` and `x` are not in the same type.

Comment: Why do you think that two comparisons could be more efficient than one?

Comment: It's probably compiled to the exact same assembler code...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Because I don't know how `x>=a` is actually impemented. :-)

Comment: @Liel, unlikely, as the latter could "invoke" `x` more than once.

Comment: it depends on the implementors and the types of `a` and `x`.

Comment: You should concentrate your effort on writing decent code. Let the compiler handle the opimization

Comment: The hardware does implement both comparisons (at least in all architectures I know of) for integral types. For custom comparisons (i.e. overloaded operators) it obviously depends on the implementation, but unless something is really crappy implemented, one comparison will always be cheaper than two.

Comment: There's only one way to find out: measure it!

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, they're not equal.  The operators could be overloaded to do entirely different things.  Speaking to their performance is only relevant if they are functionally identical.

They are also functionally different in that the expressions `x` and `a` are evaluated multiple times, rather than once, in the second example.  (Credit to [Kirk's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010257/which-one-is-more-efficient-in-performance-x-a-or-xa-x-a/20010311#comment29795381_20010257) mentioning this.)  If these expressions cause side effects, or are expensive to compute, that can be relevant to either their functional or performance characteristics.

We also can't really speak to their performance at all without knowing the specific type.  Some types could have radically different performance characteristics for these operators than  some other type.  I could be mean and throw a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in my `>=` operator, just because.

Comment: Yea, and you could also implement the `>=` operator with `<` and so on, but that's ugly at best...

Answer (score 2):

When `x` and `a` are primitives, good chances are that the optimizer will convert both to the same code. However, when `x` and `a` are complex expressions with function calls, and the "less than" expression returns `false` in considerable percentage of the cases, you will see the expression with "less than or equals" perform faster. In addition, the first expression is branchless, while the second one has a branch.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is already fully reduced. There is no way to write `x >= a` that requires fewer than 1 comparison operation, which is what it does now.